# What is a typical salary raise when promoted to software lead position?

Tags: software-industry, salary, promotion, raise

I've been working for about a year in a tech company in europe as a software developer. Based on my field, technology, experience and location, I believe my salary is a little above average. I was offered a promotion to software team lead and an 8% raise.

My new job profile would be very similar to what I'm doing now but I will additionally be managing several developers and be responsible for interviewing and onboarding of new team members.

Is there a typical raise associated with being promoted to the lead level, and if so, what is it? To me intuitively the 8% raise feels low, given the new responsibilities.

Should I ask for more or be happy with a good offer?

---

Side note which may or may not be relevant: my company does not have any existing process for adjusting wages based on inflation and after accounting for current inflation rate, the raise I was offered would be minimal.

Comment: please let me know if you need more details to be able to answer, although note that i would prefer not to disclose potentially identifying information.

Comment: I don't think giving you an average percentage is not very meaningful. The role of "Lead developer" is very differently defined across the landscape and so are salaries of software developers. 
Instead of looking at percentage increase you should look at what your responsibilities are and what skills you bring to the table, and then compare it to what you could get at different company in a similar function. 
If you don't know what you would make at other companies, there is a simple way to find out: Apply!

Comment: could you please explain the downvotes? this is my first post in this community, am i doing something wrong?

Comment: With no information about what job title you hold now, what title (is it a real title change?) you are getting, if your company has salary bands and what they are, what others are getting paid…. No one can do anything but guess.  Some people become “lead” and get nothing, others do, a lot of factors go into it. Is 8% bad “on average,” whatever that means?  No.  Is it bad for you?  Improving your question with necessary details might let us say.

Comment: The location and the company type would be good to know. For instance, I'm no sure if these salary bands would apply to you. https://www.levels.fyi/

Comment: i don't know if my company has "salary bands" and what others in the company are making, this information is not disclosed with me. added info about company type and location (is "europe" enough or too generic?).

Comment: can't believe this question was closed. it's not about "company-specific regulations", i'm clearly asking whether there are general rules or patterns... this and downvotes, what an unwelcoming community. won't be back.

Answer (score 10):

> Is there a typical raise associated with being promoted to the lead level,

No. This can vary all over the place depending on your specific circumstances, country, company specifics and local culture.

In the US many larger companies use "job grades" and "salary bands" to determine compensation, although they rarely talk about it.

Your compensation is a function or your salary band (determined by your job grad), your current salary inside the band and your performance. Sitting low in the band and having high performance typically gets you sizable raise but very time, you move through the band and eventually max out regardless of performance.

That's were a promotion comes in: a "real" promotion (in my definition) comes with a higher job grade (and salary band). A promotion inside the same grade is just window dressing.

The difference between bands can be anywhere between 10% and 25%. That doesn't mean that you get that amount as a raise: you often move from a high point in the lower band to a lower point in the higher band. That's a good thing: you have lots more room to grow in the higher band.

Your best shot is to put the details of your old and new job into a compensation comparison website like salary.com.

Comment: In my experience in companies with this sort of system  the bands overlap, and the company guarantees that you will get at least X% with the promotion even if you were at the top of the lower band.

Comment: OP got 8%. That doesn't seem an unreasonable band jump

Answer (score 2):

In many companies in the US, to get more than a 5-10% raise, or for many, even more than a 5% raise, you need to switch companies.

It's a sad fact, and some companies are getting better about it, but largely you more or less have to threaten to leave, and getting a raise as part of retention / a counteroffer isn't worth it anyway.

So unfortunately many people who believe they're 15-40% under where they should be salary-wise, leave , go somewhere else, then maybe come back to the company 2-3 years later and get 10-30% pay bumps on either hop. I've worked at a company where people did that often, it was crazy.

Essentially, when they create an SOW / budget for a new employee, they have a range for the salary, then may end up getting approval if they need some % more. When you already work there, they likely only have 5-10% budgeted for raises each year, and a very very small number of exceptions. So it's easier to get bigger pay bumps switching jobs, unfortunately.